# jquery remove class type with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a problem with jQuery. I want that the header change when you scroll on a website. But my problem is that i can't change the header multiple times.

I have a beginning, it works. But now i want that if tou scroll less than 304 pixels ONLY the opacity will be gone.

This is my code

```
$(function() {
var header = $(".clearHeader");
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 170 && scroll <= 305) {
        header.removeClass('clearHeader extraHeader').addClass('darkHeader');
    } 
    else if (scroll >= 305) {
        $('.aanvraag-button').css({"opacity":"1"});
    } 
    else {
        header.removeClass('darkHeader extraHeader').addClass('clearHeader');
    }
});
});
```

Everything just works fine, but i want that the opcaity will be gone if you go under the 304 pixels.
I did try it with multiple things like remove the class or set opacity on "" (empty) or "0" but this didn't work.

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Last question was about that everthing goes away in once. But now i want that only the opacity goes away and not the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand you correctly, this should do it:

```
var button = $('.aanvraag-button');
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),

    if (scroll >= 305) {
        button.css({opacity: 1});
    } 
    else if (scroll <= 304) {
        button.css({opacity: 0});
    }

});
```

If you want something to happen with the header too just put it inside `$(window).scroll()`.